# How to Delete All Lines That Have Duplicates

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have a text file and I need to delete every line that is duplicated, for instance:

```
line1
line2
line3
line2
line1
```

Would result in:

```
line 3
```

Is there any way I can do this with batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Quick and dirty":

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%b in ('find /c "%%a" file.txt^|find ":"') do (
    if "%%b" == " 1" echo %%a
  )
)
```

Note: this will read `file.txt` for each line, so it might be slow on a big file.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick, only issue is I'm dealing with fairly large files. :/

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-shell-removing-duplicate-lines/)

It will work well in Linux, Mac and Cygwyn.

```
sort inputfile.txt | uniq -u
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for an answer specific to windows (and Cygwin isn't an option). Edited the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We could emulate the Linux's `sort inputfile.txt | uniq -u` solution in Batch, but if the file is large, the best method is use JScript language to program the "uniq" part, so it run faster:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
sort file.txt | cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
goto :EOF

@end

// JScript section, emulate Linux's "uniq -u"

var n = 1, line1 = WScript.Stdin.ReadLine(), line2;
while ( !WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   while ( (!WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream) && (line1 == (line2=WScript.Stdin.ReadLine())) ) ++n;
   if ( n == 1 ) WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line1);
   n = 1, line1 = line2;
}
if ( n == 1 ) WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(line1);
```